# How can I delegate a derived class to use it's parents constructor?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have this basic code:

```
class Parent{
  protected:
    int _save;
  public:
    Parent(int save){
      _save = save;
    }
};

class Child : public Parent{
};
```

I can instantiate a object of type `Parent` by using this line:

`Parent test(3);`

How can I delegate the derived class to use the same constructor as it's base class so that I can instantiate it like this?:

`Child test(3);`

Comment: You should edit your original question rather than deleting it and posting the same question again

Comment: @M.M Will do in the future, although downvoting this question really doesn't make any sense for that reason. Even though I fundamentally changed the entire way my question was structured, the 4+ downvotes would've stuck to it .

Comment: Well you could delete this, and edit and undelete the other

Comment: @M.M Refer to the edit to my last comment I just made.

Comment: People can re-cast their votes after an edit . Also you repeat the mistake of posting fake code that doesn't compile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inherit the constructor with the help of a `using` declaration (requires C++11 or later):

```
class Child : public Product {
public:
    using Product::Product;
};
```

All constructor of `Product` will then be available as constructors of `Child`.

Alternatively you can delegate a single constructor using the *member initializer list*:

```
class Child : public Product {
public:
    Child(int save) : Product(save) {}
};
```

Comment: When using the first solution I get this: `error: using declaration cannot refer to a constructor`

Comment: @Laif You need to compile against at least C++11. What compiler are you using?

Comment: I'm using cmake, the line I had was `set(GLOBAL tgt PROPERTY C_STANDARD 11)` Which apparently wasn't compiling as C++11, I changed it to `set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)` and it appears to be working now. This explains the initial issues I was having haha.

Comment: @Laif Going by the naming `C_STANDARD` sets the *C* standard version (which would be irrelevant if you compile only C++), not the *C++* standard version. There happened to be a 2011 C standard iteration as well as a 2011 C++ standard iteration. If you don't need your code to be compatible with older compilers, I suggest you go for `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14` or `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17` to get the newer features. (The C++20 draft was recently finalized as well, but is not yet published.)

Comment: The programs I am working on unfortunately have to be turned in for an assignment, the professor of which compiles in C++11 for grading